# PM2 crashes while using ES modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pm2

Ive enabled ES modules in `pacakage.json` with this key value pair `"type": "module"` i dont have to use the 'experimental' flag with the latest version of node

when i run `pm2 start app.js --watch` the app crashes with the error message

```
0|app    | Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
0|app    |     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:781:11)
0|app    |     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
0|app    |     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
0|app    |     at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:164:28)
0|app    |     at importModuleDynamically (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1194:27)
0|app    |     at exports.importModuleDynamicallyCallback (internal/process/esm_loader.js:30:14)
0|app    |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:29:24)
0|app    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
0|app    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
0|app    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32) {
0|app    |   code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
0|app    | }
```

the app works perfectly fine without pm2. im guessing pm2 does not support ESM yet!

any workarounds or am i missing some configurations?

Comment: It might relate to how you import the js file in another file. Do you use an absolute path?

Comment: @ChickenSoups both importing nodejs core modules (relative path) and absolute paths to scripts dont work

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass harmony as node arguments as it will enable es6 features in pm2 process.

```
pm2 start my_app.js --watch --node-args="--harmony"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows 10

pm2 not working with esm on windows 10, there are no workarounds!

Comment: reference https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4819

Comment: is this fixed? i have to change my tooling, causing delays, and indirect issues.